# What does "To stab in the dark" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Hello I am learning english for work and I read this phrase in an article.

Comment: It sounds wrong to me. Shouldn't the idiom be [*"took a stab in the dark"*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+stab+in+the+dark) rather than *"stabbed in the dark"*. What is the actual quote from the article?

Comment: It doesn't sound "wrong" to me, but [***shot** is far more common than **stab***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+stab+in+the+dark%2Ca+shot+in+the+dark&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) in the metaphoric usage, as shown by that NGram (I'm sure the small number of *literal* usages aren't significant for those exact search strings).

Answer (score 3):

I quote a phrase [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-stab-in-the-dark) dictionary for *"A stab in the dark"*:

> A guess or attempt that is not based on knowledge or experience and
>   is very likely to be wrong or to fail

It basically means when you don't know something for sure, but you give it a shot.

It is used by different forms in other languages too, such as **A shot in the darnkess** (persian) or **A blind toss** (turkish, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: That's the definition for *"**a** stab in the dark"*, not *"**to** stab in the dark."* As far as I can tell, people hardly ever say *"I stabbed in the dark and got the right answer."* They say *"I took a stab in the dark ..."*. Very likely, that's the phrase the OP saw.   But it's not his actual question.

Comment: @PeterShor I linked the dictionary page. The OP didn't mention the exact phrase that he was reading in the article, so it might be his interpretation that it's actually _"to stab in the dark"_ rather than _"to take a stab in the dark"_.

Comment: You linked the dictionary page, but the answer would be greatly improved if you put the actual phrase the dictionary is defining ***in the answer***.

Comment: @PeterShor I added the exact phrase from the dic. If it wasn't what the OP is looking for, i'll delete this.

Comment: @PeterShor Btw i understand your concerns, to an English teacher, _"A dog"_ and _"One dog"_ are quite different, while to an English learner (which the OP claims to be) they might mean the same.